# Cannot get REPL prompt with figwheel-main and Clojure Tools

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, figwheel

My goal is to have a ClojureScript REPL (targeting Node.js) using Figwheel and Clojure Tools (not Leiningen). But when I launch Figwheel it seems to start correctly but never completes.

**deps.edn**

```clj
{:deps {org.clojure/clojure {:mvn/version "1.11.1"}
        org.clojure/clojurescript {:mvn/version "1.11.60"}}
 :aliases {:fig {:extra-deps {com.bhauman/figwheel-main {:mvn/version "0.2.18"}}}}
 :paths ["src" "target" "resources"]}
```

**dev.cljs.edn**

```clj
{:main cljs-example.foo
 :target :nodejs
 :optimizations :none
 :pretty-print true
 :source-map true
 :asset-path "js/dev"
 :output-to "resources/public/js/dev.js"
 :output-dir "resources/public/js/dev"}
```

**Launch command**

```
clj -M:fig -m figwheel.main -b dev -r
```

```
 % clj -M:fig -m figwheel.main -b dev -r 
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[Figwheel] Compiling build dev to "resources/public/js/dev.js"
[Figwheel] Successfully compiled build dev to "resources/public/js/dev.js" in 0.708 seconds.
[Figwheel] Watching paths: ("src") to compile build - dev
[Figwheel] Starting Server at http://localhost:9500
[Figwheel] Starting REPL
Prompt will show when REPL connects to evaluation environment (i.e. Node)
Figwheel Main Controls:
          (figwheel.main/stop-builds id ...)  ;; stops Figwheel autobuilder for ids
          (figwheel.main/start-builds id ...) ;; starts autobuilder focused on ids
          (figwheel.main/reset)               ;; stops, cleans, reloads config, and starts autobuilder
          (figwheel.main/build-once id ...)   ;; builds source one time
          (figwheel.main/clean id ...)        ;; deletes compiled cljs target files
          (figwheel.main/status)              ;; displays current state of system
Figwheel REPL Controls:
          (figwheel.repl/conns)               ;; displays the current connections
          (figwheel.repl/focus session-name)  ;; choose which session name to focus on
In the cljs.user ns, controls can be called without ns ie. (conns) instead of (figwheel.repl/conns)
    Docs: (doc function-name-here)
    Exit: :cljs/quit
 Results: Stored in vars *1, *2, *3, *e holds last exception object
Starting node ... 
Node output being logged to: resources/public/js/dev/node.log
For a better development experience:
  1. Open chrome://inspect/#devices ... (in Chrome)
  2. Click "Open dedicated DevTools for Node"
```

And that's it! :(

It stays like that forever and I never get a prompt such as:

```
cljs.user=>
```

---

**Addendum**

I don't think my `foo.cljs` file has an error that would cause Figwheel to hang. When I launch a "native" REPL with:

```
clj -M -m cljs.main --target node --compile cljs-example.foo --repl
```

Then I get:

```
ClojureScript 1.11.60
cljs.user=> (require '[cljs-example.foo])
i am foo!!!!!!!!
nil
cljs.user=>
```

Comment: Does it help when you add `-re node`? Is your project public? This way it's easier to clone and diagnose.

Comment: @MichielBorkent Nope it's not ;) In the process of creating a repro repository I have managed to get it to work… Not sure exactly what went wrong but I hope to share my results soon. Thanks for your reply though.